# vuetify electron github page showing page not found

Tags: github, vuetify.js

when I was starting to create a new vuetify electron project by vuecli3,
I used command "vue init vuetifyjs/electron project_name"
a vuecli error shown failed to download repo vuetifyjs/electron : response code 404 (Not Found)

then I go to see the instructions on vuetify page, I found out that the page on 'https://github.com/vuetifyjs/electron' also showing page not found.
I also found out that other temples were also missing like PWA and other

So is there any alternative way to start a project of verify electron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Vue Cli 3 and add the Vuetify plugin and the Electron plugin:

```
vue create my-app
cd my-app
vue add vuetify
vue add electron-builder
yarn electron:serve
```